# how to hide javascript code

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I obfuscate JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-javascript)

Hello!

Is it possible to hide JS code? How?  I read somewhere a technique like: take JS to external file, and use js-encrypt.

I know that is impossible to hide from all eyes, but...

Thank you.

Comment: What's so secret about your JS code?

Comment: @ceejayoz what's so secret about any code? Kind of a naive question. There are plenty of good reasons for wanting to hide code.

Comment: please don't tell me you're hiding passwords or any other sensitive data in javascript. :D

Comment: no, I don't really see why hiding JS code. You shouldn't do no black magic neither sensitive operations there, so I don't see why hiding it.

Comment: what if i want to sell JS code? And i have several demo code on my site? (i dont want...just an example..)

Comment: @apphacker In my experience, the vast majority of people asking about how to protect CSS/HTML/JS code (or disabling right-click on images) are those not at risk of having their code "stolen".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17468822/2450730

Comment: Use Encode.js : encodejs.devincity.com

Answer (score 12):

It is not possible to hide Javascript from the user, since their browser needs to download it to execute it. The only other option is [obfuscation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscated_code).

Comment: I agree; security through obscurity isn't very good security at all...

Comment: Well, IMO is not even security.

Comment: @chris-l reminds me of a quote from information security class: "Securtity is not hiding the door. It's putting the door in front of them, telling them how it's locked, and they STILL can't get in."

Comment: Use Encode.js : encodejs.devincity.com

Answer (score 8):

You can run your private JavaScript server side e.g. using ASP [JScript.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974588.aspx)

```
<% WebService Language="JScript" Class="MyClass" %>
```

You can put the hidden functionality on the server and call it via AJAX in the non hidden part of the code on the client.

you can also use

```
<script runat="server">
```

or if you're not using a Microsoft platform you might consider [Mozilla Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/)

Comment: Seems like a flippant response but it's the only solution to hiding code.

Comment: I guess the more modern answer would be to use node.js + socket.io for this kind of thing.

Comment: Or if not using a server-side platform that supports JS just use whatever server-side language is supported. Assuming that the code to be hidden is something that can be done on the server at all, for example you can't move a game's event handlers to server-side.

Comment: @PeanutPower any pointers on how to do that, any guides or tutorials?

Comment: How is Rhino? Can you use it in JSP?

Answer (score 1):

As you can take someone else's code and try to encrypt it, same goes for others who can take your code. The only solution that i think is to obfuscate your javascript code so that it becomes little difficult for others to grasp but there again there decryptors available so no real solution as of what i know has come about so far.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no - since the browser needs to understand the javascript, then the user will be able to understand the javascript...

Comment: Use Encode.js : encodejs.devincity.com