# Hiding javascript in the page

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a webpage which has an external javascript file attached to it . Now in firebug , I can see all the js code and so can anyone else , is there a way so that the code can be hidden but it would still work?

Comment: Almost all JavaScript code on the internet is public. If you want to hide the code, I suggest you to move it to the server-side.

Comment: No, you cannot. This has been asked to death [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222355/how-to-hide-javascript-code) and it's still not possible!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. There is no way to do that. That's not how the internet works. You cannot do that. Stop worrying about it. You cannot send a file and expect the file not to be sent.

Answer (score 1):

The #1 law of software licensing: You don't control your software once you allow it to be <strike>installed</strike> run on a computer you don't control.

(blatently stolen from my own answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532540/c-how-to-make-it-harder-for-hacker-cracker-to-get-around-or-bypass-the-licensin/4532568#4532568))