# How to protect a video file in html?

Tags: javascript, html, video, media, mp4

If someone adds a video to a webpage using the video tag you can find its link in the source code of the webpage very easily and download it. But websites like netflix, lynda, hulo, youtube, vimeo, dailymotion etc somehow manage to prevent you from being able to do it. How do they do it? How can I do it? I tried googling but didn't find anything useful. Can anyone help?

P.S I would like a client-side solution so if possible no php, perl, ruby etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent Video downloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582433/prevent-video-downloading)

Comment: that question is tagged php which i would like to avoid if possible please

Comment: The answer to that question is the same as the answer to this question. It is not platform- or language-dependent.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Did you bother to actually read the post he linked as duplicate? Judging by your comments I'm fairly certain you didn't. If you do read it then you will come to the answer, which has nothing to do with the server language, as has been stated.

Answer (score 1):

They are using flash from what i can see. But with just a video tag, you can not protect its source.
This was an interesting question !

Comment: can u tell me how