# Get SCSI hard drive serial on Linux from a C++ program

Tags: c++, linux, hard-drive

I want to retrieve SCSI hard drive serial on Linux (Ubuntu) from a C++ program without root priveleges. I tried ioctl(fd, HDIO_GET_IDENTITY, &id) but it seems to work only for ATA devices. Does anyone have a solution for SCSI HDDs? The solution I am looking for should not require the user to have root priveleges. Any source code will be much appreciated

Comment: You're going to need permission from root, for the same reasons explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985270/how-to-get-motherboard-id-on-linux-from-a-c-program)

Comment: You are still doing it wrong... sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about sending a [SCSI Inquiry command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCSI_Inquiry_Command), as described here: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/archived/SCSI-Programming-HOWTO/SCSI-Programming-HOWTO-9.html

A complete program: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/archived/SCSI-Programming-HOWTO/SCSI-Programming-HOWTO-24.html

Edit: The bottom of this page shows the specific structures required for the SCSI serial number inquiry request and response: http://sunbolic.com/sunbolic/code/cpp/aspi_unit_sn.htm

Comment: I tried this code on my Ubuntu, but 1) it requires root priveleges and 2) it does not get serial, only "type and make of the device"

Comment: Aha, you have amended your question to say it has to be done without root privileges.  I think you should reconsider your entire approach to the higher-level issues at hand here, as discussed in your other question about motherboard serial numbers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985270/how-to-get-motherboard-id-on-linux-from-a-c-program

Comment: Even if we put aside root issue for now (although if someone still has non-root solution that would be ideal) which bits in this SCSI Inquiry command represent serial? Is it "Product Identification" bits 16-31?

Comment: As per the Wikipedia page, you must set the Page Code in the Inquiry command to 0x80.