# C# code at runtime?

Tags: c#, dynamic-compilation

How can I compile raw C# code at runtime? So if I want to add security by removing important pieces of code and downloading it via a server, and then execute it from within my application?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to download the source code, or a compiled version?

You can download the MSIL and use `Assembly.Load(byte[])` to load it for execution.

But none of these methods add security.  If you send the code to the user's computer in ANY format, they can capture a copy.  Never saving it to disk just adds a small speedbump.

See: [The #1 law of software licensing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532540/c-how-to-make-it-harder-for-hacker-cracker-to-get-around-or-bypass-the-licensin/4532568#4532568).

Comment: The downloaded source code is encrypted. It's an online-only program, so the inconveneice will always be there.

Comment: @Dark: Doesn't really matter, since the decryption keys are on the user's computer.  Just another speedbump, no real security.

Comment: @Dark: Anyway, why send source code, when you can encrypt and send the MSIL output from the C# compiler?

Comment: Because I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @Dark: Just build a DLL project.  Send that file, when you decrypt it on the receiving side, instead of writing it to disk, call `Assembly.Load(byte[])`.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this a while ago to simplify code execution, hope it helps:

[CSharpCompiler](http://pastebin.com/NnE8pje8)