# Grab .net Process In Memory

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to secure a small-medium sized MMO i've written in c# and we are having some problems with hacking. I would like to know if there is a way to grab the copy of the process that is currently in memory, and not on disk. We have a very secure algorithm in the game however it cannot stop people modifying the in memory version of the game.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`MiniDumpWriteDump`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function can capture the entire application, inclusive of state.  Usually used for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can access the operating memory when you have the privileges. Hackers can do it easily.

Answer (score 0):

```
Step 1: Attach a debugger.
Step 2: Hack!
```

It is rather difficult to keep anything in your code secret when your code is running on someone else's computer.

Comment: Or as I say: ["The #1 law of software licensing: You don't control your software once you allow it to be installed on a computer you don't control."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532540/c-how-to-make-it-harder-for-hacker-cracker-to-get-around-or-bypass-the-licensin/4532568#4532568)