# how to search the memory of an open process for a byte[] array

Tags: c#

is it possible  in C# to search the memory of an open process byte[] array for a pattern  e.g. { 0x97, 0x35, 0x15, 0xC3, ??, 0x80, 0xE4} and return the address ? so then i can use the address in WriteProcessMemory

Comment: There are a few answers in this duplicate question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/781716/c-search-a-byte-array-in-another-processs-memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/781716/c-search-a-byte-array-in-another-processs-memory)

Comment: You ought to get in touch with this guy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760895/grab-net-process-in-memory

Comment: Thanks i will see if i can get hold of one of those guys as they seem to be seeking the same as me

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Code Project article about implementing a [memory scanner in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/sojaner_memory_scanner.aspx). Although I think you'll have to modify it a bit so you can write on the same address where you read the values.