# How to avoid tampering of javascript / HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html, security

in my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u1zugr9L/5/) I have an example that should only allow a user to click submit by turning the submit button element disabled to false based on some calculated javascript.

```
  function enable(TVD) {
    if (TVD[TVD.length - 1] >= trueTVD - 5 && TVD[TVD.length - 1] <= trueTVD + 5) {
      //console.log(TVD[TVD.length - 1]);
      $('#submitButton').prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
      $('#submitButton').prop("disabled", true);
    }
  }
```

What has happened is that I have found that some users have managed to bypass this presumably by using something like dev tools.

I would like to design this such that my security cant be bypassed. How do I accomplish this goal or hide the javascript from dev tools?

Comment: I'm no expert, but I'd imagine that sort of protection would need to be implemented server-side.

Comment: Server side validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The best way is validate on the server. Never trust anything that comes from a client. It could be tampered with.
2. It's never completely possible to stop dev-tools from being loaded, however you can make it difficult by disabling the F12-button and contextmenus, **but that's a road you don't want to walk on.**
3. Use code that is minified, so it becomes much harder to read and comprehend and to tamper with using dev-tools or other sniffers.

> summerized: use minified (obfuscated) code in combination with sanity checks on the client and on the server (preferable on the database too).

Comment: Good to know, Unfortunately a 3rd party (Amazon Turk) hosts the server where submit will be sent to so even if I ping my own server with info it wont stop someone from clicking submit.

Comment: Still you can post these to your server and use a curl in php to get results.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: You can't

Long answer: Everyone can send anything to your server. The only way to securely filter and check the user input is therefore on the server side only

Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Afaik, you can't hide javascript code to users. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222355/how-to-hide-javascript-code).

A low level way of achieving obfuscation would be to have minified javascript files, as most users wouldn't bother tracing single letter named variables and such.

Comment: It's not all about javascript, you can manipulate DOM (e.g. enable a button) without looking into code.